# How to create multiple column from an column value using split functions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column where i am looking to split the column value using the split function. Having the column name as the first character and column value as the 2nd character split by:

**Input data**

```
Column1   Column2 

Item1    Material, Teflon ; MODEL: 28' Inches ; MAKE : SAMSUNG ; SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: AW Tech ; POWER INPUT :65W @240 VOLTS ; NO OF INPUTS : 4 ; METHOD : AIR COOLED ; TYPE : LED
Item1    Material, PLASTIC ; MODEL: 55' Inches ; MAKE : SONY ; SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: DK MART ; POWER INPUT :55W @240 VOLTS ; NO OF INPUTS : 5 ; METHOD : NEO AIR COOLED ; TYPE : SMART LED
Item1    Material, Teflon ; MODEL: 42' Inches ; MAKE : LG ; SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: AW Tech ; POWER INPUT :65W @240 VOLTS ; NO OF INPUTS : 4 ; METHOD : AIR COOLED ; TYPE : LED
Item1     MATERIAL, PLASTIC ; MAKE  : VIDEOCON ; POWER INPUT        : 22V /240 VOLT ; COMPLETED UNIT ; SPARES
Item1    MATERIAL ; MAKE : SONY ; SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: AW Tech; ; COMPLETED UNIT ; UNIT PARTS
```

**Expected output**

```
Item                MODEL       Make    Supplier/PO Details  Power Input    No Of Inputs  Method      Type      Completed Units

Material, Teflon    28' Inches  SAMSUNG       AW Tech        65W @240 VOLTS     4        Air Cooled    LED        
Material, PLASTIC   55' Inches  SONY          DK Material    55W @240 VOLTS     5      NEO AIR COOLED Smart LED    
Material, Teflon    42' Inches  LG            AW Tech        65W @240 VOLTS     4        Air Cooled    LED  
MATERIAL, PLASTIC               VIDEOCON                     22V /240 VOLTS                                         SPARES
Material                        SONY          AW Tech                                                               UNIT PARTS
```

**Code i have been trying :**

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Input\Test.csv")

for row in df.Column2:
  cols = row.split(';')
```

How can i create different column using the Column2 values and assign the respected values to the respective column names?

Comment: We can code this, but it looks like you're trying to decode json except you threw the quotes away (`'MAKE' : 'SAMSUNG'`), which makes it harder. Can you please regenerate the input with the quotes left in?

Comment: @smci - The input is same as it is in the question. I am looking to go through Colum2 create column with the keys, and assign the values to it. Once the column is created need to assign the values of rest of the rows. As Specified in the Expected output.

Comment: @James -  Is there anything wrong in the Typos , As you  are editing the Question

Comment: Yes, I fixed your question, and for some reason you decided to roll it back. Can you explain why? Was there something wrong in my edit?

Answer (score 1):

First **split on the semicolons between the 8 fields**, with optional trailing whitespace.

```
df['Column2'].str.split(r';[ ]*')
```

This gives you a list with 8 string elements:

```
['Material, Teflon ', "MODEL: 28' Inches ", 'MAKE : SAMSUNG ', 'SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: AW Tech ', 'POWER INPUT :65W @240 VOLTS ', 'NO OF INPUTS : 4 ', 'METHOD : AIR COOLED ', 'TYPE : LED']
['Material, PLASTIC ', "MODEL: 55' Inches ", 'MAKE : SONY ', 'SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: DK MART ', 'POWER INPUT :55W @240 VOLTS ', 'NO OF INPUTS : 5 ', 'METHOD : NEO AIR COOLED ', 'TYPE : SMART LED']
['Material, Teflon ', "MODEL: 42' Inches ", 'MAKE : LG ', 'SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: AW Tech ', 'POWER INPUT :65W @240 VOLTS ', 'NO OF INPUTS : 4 ', 'METHOD : AIR COOLED ', 'TYPE : LED']
['MATERIAL, PLASTIC ', 'MAKE  : VIDEOCON ', 'POWER INPUT        : 22V /240 VOLT ', 'COMPLETED UNIT ', 'SPARES']
['MATERIAL ', 'MAKE : SONY ', 'SUPPLIER/PO DETAILS: AW Tech', '', 'COMPLETED UNIT ', 'UNIT PARTS']
```

Second, each of those fields has an optional field name and trailing colon e.g. 'MAKE :'. You can simply rsplit on the optional colon, and take the [-1] item, i.e. throw away any field name:

```
def strip_optional_fields(f):
    result_list = []
    for ff in f:
        if ff.find(':') >= 0:
            result_list.append(ff.rsplit(':')[-1])
        else:
            result_list.append(ff)  # empty-string
    return pd.Series(result_list)
```

You can get view that output with:

```
df['Column2'].str.split(r';[ ]*').apply(strip_optional_fields)
```

...or concatenate them to new columns on the right with:

```
pd.concat([df, df['Column2'].str.split(r';[ ]*').apply(strip_optional_fields)], axis=1)
```

then rename those by changing `df.columns`

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. How can i split the values from keys by : and assign the values to the columns using keys.

Comment: Gives Error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable" on the line "for ff in f:" ,  Please suggest how it can be resolved

Comment: @Manz: it works perfectly fine for me, I tested it, a lot. My code has no floats anywhere. So your error *"'float' object is not iterable"* on the line `for ff in f:` means you must have declared some stray float variable called `f`. Rerun the code in a clean shell and it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

The idea is to convert the data Inside the 'Column2' to dictionary

```
from ast import literal_eval


out=df['Column2'].str.title().str.split(' ; ',1,expand=True)
newout=('{"'+out[1].replace({':':'":"',' ; ':'","'},regex=True)+'"}')
newout=newout.str.rsplit(',',1,expand=True)
m=~(newout[1].str.contains(':').fillna(True))
newout.loc[m,0]=newout.loc[m,0]+':'+newout.loc[m,1]
newout.loc[~m,0]=newout.loc[~m,0]+','+newout.loc[~m,1]
newout=pd.DataFrame(newout[0].dropna().astype(str).map(literal_eval).tolist())
newout.insert(0,'Item',out[0])
newout.columns=newout.columns.str.strip()
```

Now if you print `newout` you will get your desired dataframe

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, But while executing i am getting the Error TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float' on the Line "m=~newout[1].str.contains(':')" , It seems to be due to the NaN value , Please suggest how to resolve it.

Comment: @Manz updated answer...now try...If it doesn't work then let me know **:)**

Comment: Thanks for the help. But while using m=~(newout[1].str.contains(':').fillna(False)) getting the error "ValueError: malformed node or string: nan" on line  "newout=pd.DataFrame(newout[0].map(literal_eval).tolist())". by Using dropna() then gets the Error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" on the same line "newout=pd.DataFrame(newout[0].map(literal_eval).tolist())"

Comment: Thank You Anurag, Still getting the Error "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" , When Executing the line, "newout=pd.DataFrame(newout[0].dropna().map(literal_eval).tolist())" , Any Suggestion where i am getting wrong.

Comment: @Manz what was the full traceback?...because it was working for given sample dataframe

Comment: Please refer to the question where i have mentioned the Error. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429673/create-new-columns-from-existing-column-values-using-split-function

Comment: @Manz can you now try?...updated answer kindly have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and use `expand=True` if you want to create extra columns for the splitted values,

```
df_expanded = df['Column2'].str.split(r';[ ]*', expand=True)
```

You can then individually process these columns to remove any prefix / suffix you like to remove.